# how to debug in crxde eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, aem, crx, day-cq

right now I am having difficulties with debugging my simple jsp pages in Crxde eclipse. I am following [This link for debugging](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQ5HowToSetupRemoteDebuggingWithEclipse.html) but I am not able to debug my application, debugger switches to debug perspective but it does not stop on break point.

Comment: Try this "http://therealcq.blogspot.com/2012/12/running-and-debugging-cq5-using-crxde.html"

Comment: @VAr this link is broken :(

Comment: http://therealcq.blogspot.in/2012/12/running-and-debugging-cq5-using-crxde.html